# exporting to exel file error in response end

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I try to export excel from a function in my data access layer which return `dataTable`. Now my question is why my `Response.end` return an error.
The datagrid have datas

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

My export code

```
if (command == "export") {
    StringWriter osStringWritter = new StringWriter();
    Html32TextWriter osHtmlTextWritter = new Html32TextWriter(osStringWritter);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataGrid dgv = new DataGrid();
    PostTransDA transaction = new PostTransDA();
    try {

        dt = transaction.getTransaction(from_Dates, to_dates);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", "TransactionReport"));
            Response.Charset = "";

            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            dgv.DataBind();

            dgv.RenderControl(osHtmlTextWritter);
            Response.Write("Report Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            Response.Write(osStringWritter.ToString());
            Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

            dgv = null;
            osStringWritter = null;
            osHtmlTextWritter = null;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Script", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
    }
}
```

its return the error on the part of `Response.End()`
what im doing wrong? or what is the problem in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check link given below for issues you have. You need to **handle ThreadAbortException when you are using either Response.End or Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer**.

[Microsoft link for Best practices to avoid ThreadAbortException](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir)

Comment: no error now on response end but nothings happening its not exporting excel its just reading the code then do nothing, any idea why?

Comment: Check on this link, use code exactly describe here and see what happens. https://web.archive.org/web/20071211120622/http://tim.mackey.ie/HowtoExportADatasetToExcelCAspnet.aspx

Comment: comment these two lines and check. 
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: bro still nohing happens

Comment: did you tried using code from link given in my above comment?

Comment: no worries bro i just solve it .The reason is my  button is not fully posting back